# Какие объекты можно помещать в сессию?

Tags: asp.net, сессия

Может ли помещаемый в `HttpContext.Current.Session` объект содержать в себе вложенные объекты? Какие еще накладываются ограничения? Что с конструкторами классов, они вызываются при извлечении из сессии?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объекты, помещаемые в сессию должны реализовать интерфейс ISerializable, то есть обычно достаточно просто пометить соответствующим атрибутом (Serializable) ваши классы, которые будут храниться в сессии. При извлечении объектов из сессии используется механизм десериализации.

Comment: А с добавлением/извлечением `ArrayList` никаких проблем нету, насколько я понял?

Comment: Проблем быть не должно.

Comment: Проблем не будет, так как данный тип сериализируемый!